# Infinite symmetric product of an $H$-space and graded product structure on homotopy groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, graded-rings, higher-homotopy-groups

Assume $X$ is an $H$-space and let's look at homotopy groups of $SP(X)$ where $SP$ here is the infinite symmetric product. By Dold-Thom we have $\pi_i(SP(X))\cong \tilde{H}_i(X)$. Since  $X$ is an $H$-space there is a graded product structure on $\tilde{H}_i(X)$ for $i>0$. So this implies that there is a graded product structure on $\pi_i(SP(X))$ for $i>0$. So I was wondering whether it is possible to realize this graded product structure in more geometric way and in the form of a smash product on $SP(X)$? Is there a map $SP(X)\wedge SP(X) \rightarrow SP(X)$ that does this?

To me it seems that we have a map $SP(X)\wedge SP(X) \rightarrow SP(X\wedge X)$, unless we have a smash product on $X$ we won't get a map to $SP(X)$. The smash product on $X$ seems to be something independent of the $H$-space structure.

So another related question is that do nice $H$-spaces  also admit a smash product i.e. $X\wedge X \rightarrow X$ where this product somehow depends on the $H$-space structure? (For all smash products let's assume the base point is the identity $e$)

Here is an idea not sure whether it is relevant or not. If $X$ admits a de-loop, $BX$, then the Whitehead product on homotopy groups of $BX$ turns into a graded product structure on the homotopy groups of $X$, not sure whether this is related to the graded product structure coming from Dold-Thom or not.

Comment: The graded product structure is defined on $H_*(X)$, not on $\tilde H_*(X)$.

Comment: @Tyrone If it is defined on Homology, then it is also defined in reduced Homology. I did not claim the graded ring, just product.

Comment: Why do you think it should be defined on reduced homology if it is defined on unreduced homology? The Pontryagin product makes use of the unreduced external product $H_*(X)\otimes H_*(X)\rightarrow H_*(X\times X)$ which you do not have in reduced homology. To convert reduced to unreduced you add a disjoint basepoint. Then $X_+\wedge X_+\cong (X\times X)_+\xrightarrow{(\mu_+)_*}X_+$ is the map you are looking for, where $\mu$ is the H-space multiplication on $X$.

Comment: @Tyrone The incovenience of reducedness comes through Dold-Thom. Yes the product is on homology now ignore degree zero that product should induce a product on homotopy group in positive degrees. The plus sign means you are adding an extra disjoint point, although what you have written is true but it does not equip the homotopy groups with any form of graded product. Because homotopy groups of $X_+$ if you force the basepoint on the sphere to go to that disjoint point will be all zero. Unless you can somehow provide a nice topology on it, does not help to get the graded product.

Comment: You do not need the homotopy groups of $X_+$. Rather those of $SP(X_+)$, which are $\tilde H_*(X_+)=H_*(X)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Interesting, but now $X_+$ is not connected and you can't use Dold-Thom on $SP(X_+)$. Or am I missing something? but this case might be true I have to check.

Comment: I think zeroth homotopy becomes a monoid such that its group completion is integers, so at degree zero they don't quite match but elsewhere they do.

Comment: That's a fair criticism. You can pass to suspensions and proceed ($\Sigma(X_+)\simeq (\Sigma X)\vee S^1$ makes everything work out as expected). But this seems quite artificial.

Comment: @Tyrone Cool. Now do you know how to show this coincides with the ponteryagin product? or any resource will be helpful. This turns into my previous question on this website.

Comment: Yes. The reference I couldn't find last night was McCord's paper [Classifying Spaces and Infinite Symmetric Product](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-146-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251719-4/S0002-9947-1969-0251719-4.pdf). See Theorem 11.4 for a statement of the Dold-Thom theorem that does not require connectedness.

Comment: @Tyrone, Great paper but doesn't seem to be rigorous. Although he claims the two homology cross products are the same, but he only shows they have similar properties. Do you know why they have to be the same given the anti-commutativity property?